# Enabling Web Socket has disappeared from App Service configuration

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Within my App Service property in Azure I normally have an option to enable Web sockets. It seems that this option has been very recently removed. Is anyone able to advise if this is no longer supported or if I am doing something wrong?

[image]

Additional Information:

- Azure App Plan is a B1
  [image]

Comment: Is your App service   Linux or Windows  OS ? Web Sockets option is available only for windows OS

Comment: Use this Command to enable the option `az webapp config set --web-sockets-enabled true --name MyAppName --resource-group MyResourceGroup`

Answer (score 4):

As MS said, you don't need to enable it because it's always enabled
[faqs-app-service-linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/faqs-app-service-linux#web-sockets)

[image: foto de origen]

Answer (score 1):

> Enabling Web Socket has disappeared from App Service configuration

- If you have hosted your Web App using `Linux OS`,

[image]

then as per this  [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/general/faqs-app-service-linux#web-sockets))

> Web Sockets are not currently supported for Linux apps on Free App Service Plans.

I have created another App Service with Windows OS with  B1 Plan , I am able to see the option of Web Sockets in Configuration section

[image]

Comment: Have you read that wrong? The link you provided says "Web Sockets are now supported for Linux apps on Free App Service plans. "... Maybe it has changed since you answered.  It also says Web sockets are always enabled for Linux, which is why there is no option to turn them on or off: "The webSocketsEnabled ARM setting does not apply to Linux apps since Web Sockets are always enabled for Linux."