# Blazor Server Side + Azure SignalR + Linux App Service Hosting Plan

Tags: blazor-server-side, azure-appservice, azure-signalr

I am currently hosting my Blazor Server app on a Windows Based Azure App Service because of the Web Sockets requirement (which the Linux variants does not seem to possess even on the Basic Tier).

So I was wondering whether it would be possible to host on linux by moving the SingalR component to a dedicated service to replace the Web Socket option which would then allow me to host the base Blazor Server application on a linux based app service plan.

Wanted to check with the community to see if this really overcomes the problem or would I still be faced with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, found the answer in this post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74617028/2585152

Looks like web sockets on Linux are on by default